# get cart items from custom column value

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, products, quoteitem, sales-quote

I have a custom column in my  sales_flat_quote_item table named as device_id.
I am working on to create a api where a device id is sent and the cart available items are displayed for guest users.

```
$deviceId=802;
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($deviceId);
$cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
echo $pid = $item->getProductId();
}
```

which is not working.Is this not the proper way ?Please help thanks

Comment: load returns only one(first) value

Comment: try the 3rd way that is complete good answer for you

Answer (score 1):

you can do, try below code tested by me

```
$deviceId=802;  //if your value in ales_flat_quote table
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($deviceId,'device_id');//here device_id is feild in database
$cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
  echo $pid = $item->getProductId();
}
```

according your comment

```
$deviceId=802;
$quote_colle = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->getCollection();
foreach($quote_colle as $quote){

  $cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
  foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
   if($item->getDeviceId()==802){
    echo $pid = $item->getProductId();
   }
  }
}
```

**3rd way**

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$deviceId=802;
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('device_id',  $deviceId);
foreach($collection as $item)
{
 echo $item->getId();
}
```

Comment: {"messages":{"error":[{"code":42,"message":"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sales_flat_quote.device_id' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT `sales_flat_quote`.* FROM `sales_flat_quote` WHERE (`sales_flat_quote`.`device_id`=11111) AND (store_id IN ('0'))"}]}}

Comment: ohh for this you have this column in `sales_flat_quote` table not in item table

Comment: what cn be done?

Comment: You want all product which has device_id=802 in quote ??

Comment: yes some thing like that so if the quote from same device id has same product id then i can update quantity

Comment: @Melvin See Updated answer

Comment: @Melvin check 3rd way

Comment: ok so i was going through the first method and added a column in sales_flat_quote .and tried your first method .But i am not able to get product id nor entity id

Comment: set store `Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);` everytime

Comment: in the first method , i have added a colum to  sales_flat_quote and tried your code.now  sales_flat_quote device id has same device id in different row.How can i fetch all of that actualy.Itried your code and got only first one

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below code:

```
$deviceId=802;
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->setStoreId(1)->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('device_id', array('eq' => $deviceId));
foreach($collection as $item)
{
  var_dump($item->getData());
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getStoreId() on a non-object in ... app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Resource\Quote\Item\Collection.php on line 67

Comment: I have updated the code. Please try with updated code

Comment: getting the same error

Comment: I think the quote is not exists for that device. Anyway adding device_id in sales_flat_quote_item table is not a good approach. Instead add device_id in sales_flat_quote table  and then use $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('device_id', array('eq' => $deviceId)); to load the quote.

Comment: If i do that how can i compare it with the product id

Comment: yes . sales_flat_quote is a parent table of sales_flat_quote_item. Also you can get quote item by calling  $quote->getAllItems();